# Excel VBA Adding Formula/Date to Last Row in a Sheet When Data is Entered

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data that I want to append the dates to when a user enters data in one of the columns in the last row only. So, if there were 4 rows of data, and the user entered anything in one of the valid columns (B:L) in the fifth row, the date would be added to the 'M' row to mark the date of entry.

Is there a way to easily do this? I could think of a simple way to add a `sub` that basically says if data in any column B:L -> add date, but I would have to call this every time a user changed the sheet or added information.

I could possibly just enter a formula in every row, but I would still have to update it when anything is overwritten or expanded. Just wondering if anyone knows of a quick solution.

Edit:

Actually using,

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = GetLastRow(Sheets("MySheet"))
    If lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B" & CStr(lastRow) & ":L" & CStr(lastRow))) Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("MySheet").Range("M" & CStr(lastRow)).value = Date
    End If
End Sub
```

Will modify anything entered past the last row at the time the sheet is changed. So, if data goes to row 6, and you enter something in row 9, it detects the last row as row 9. I've decided this is actually enough, because I'll be sorting out empty rows, but if you wanted to just modify the last row, you could use an `oldLastRow` value that is kept as a global variable. Then check to see if the sub is modified only on that value and if so, run your code then change the `oldLastRow` to the new `lastRow`.

Comment: You are right to use an event triggered sub. There is no problem with this firing every time a user makes a change.

Comment: What is the best way to detect this though? Can I set it to just a range, or would it have to be over the entire sheet? I'm asking because there may be up to 60,000 entries in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then what you're looking for is the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event of your current sheet along with a filter to ensure a specific range was updated.

To do this, in the VBA editor, go to the sheet that you want this functionality for and double-click it then put in the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not (Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("B:L")) Is Nothing) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("M" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

What this basically says is that if there is a change in any way in columns B thru L, then put the current time into column M.

Hope this does the trick!

---

**Update:**

To take the last row into account as stated in the comments:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If Not (Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("B" & LastRow & ":L" & LastRow)) Is Nothing) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect, and answers my comment from above. Thank you. It does actually modify all ranges though, which isn't a huge deal, but I figure you could call the `.Range("B" & lastRow & ":L" & lastRow)` instead to get the same result as my original question.

Comment: This doesn't contemplate the last row however, and that was one of the requirements.

Comment: Fair enough @Kyle, I'm just unsure what he'd want... DouglasTrippe, do you need to know if it was the last row, or do you want a timestamp any time the data is updated?

Comment: I basically modified the code to `If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B" & CStr(lastRow) & ":L" & CStr(lastRow))) Is Nothing Then` where lastRow is the first empty row in the sheet, if you work downward.

Comment: Thanks for the heads' up, @Kyle, updated the solution to account for that. Hope it does the trick!